# Errors while echoing CSS and image files in PHP "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

Tags: php, html

Okay so after changing around some files (I'm trying to make my whole site open-source) I still can't get the Bootstrap CSS or any image files (eg. the logo) to load on the page.
Looking in the console I get this

[image: errors in page]

What I've tried to do in the code is this -

```
echo "<link href=\"$domain/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> ";
echo "<link href=\"$domain/css/logo-nav.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> ";
```

However going to the URL's directly, clicking on them from the error log even (http://localhost:8000/site-opensource/css/logo-nav.css) loads the CSS perfectly fine.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I have tried to google it and really didn't find much help.

Cheers!

EDIT: here is a screenshot of the network tab 
[image]

Comment: Check the network tab. Check the response headers. What do they say?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3afc436a4c239ca689e57ccdff29e435 is this what you mean?

Comment: Would you edit that into your question?

Comment: So, not even a response. What do the Request headers look like? (You have to click on one of the failed requests).

Comment: Hm, do you mean like this? https://gyazo.com/e31cdd99d6e510aa6d277caa6392244d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the domain as it is not needed. The HTML automatically uses the domain of the current site. So to do that you can just change it to:

```
echo "<link href=\"/site-opensource/css/logo-nav.css)\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> ";
```

If you are using that variable because the CSS may not be in the root and is for whatever reason dynamic. You can do as so

```
echo "<link href=\"$dir/site-opensource/css/logo-nav.css)\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> ";
```

with

```
$dir = "folder1/folder2/folder3";
```

Pointing to whatever directory that the CSS is currently in.

*NOTE* that the domain is no needed at all here.